# React Native Autofocus Inputfield

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I try to focus on a inputfield after doing a navigate.goBack() in react native.

I saw some solutions using Ref. I tried it but still this type of solution is not working for me?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef  } from 'react';

const textInput = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      textInput.current.focus();   
      loadData()  
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

<TextInput      
        ref={textInput}            
        value={text}
        placeholder="Your name"
        style={styles.textInput} />
```

How can I do this in React native?
I already searched for it on Google and also on this site. But all the solutions didn't work for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

on back handling

```js
useFocusEffect(()=>{
 if(textInput.current !==null){
  textInput.current.focus()
 }
},[textInput.current])
```

Text Input

```js
<TextInput                
   value={text}
   ref={textInput}
   placeholder="Your name"
   style={styles.textInput}
   autofocus
/>
```

there you go bro, don't forget to import useFocusEffect from navigation

Comment: When I add this I get the following error: You passed a second argument to 'useFocusEffect', but it only accepts one argument. If you want to pass a dependency array, you can use 'React.useCallback':

useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    // Your code here
  }, [depA, depB])
);